# Ubuntu only os. Problems encountered

Tags: boot, mount, windows, uninstall

I don't have any other Operating System on my laptop, only Ubuntu. Ubuntu is not working properly and it doesn't boot automatically. All I can do to boot is mounting `/` in the root. How can i uninstall Ubuntu? I tried installing Windows 7 using a DVD but it can't find any drivers that are compatible with Windows. Hope I can find answers. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you check out this steps on how to [create a live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) using a friends laptop

Answer (score 0):

i recommend that you borrow a live pendrive of ubuntu (or your fav distro or any other os) from your friend and then try installing everything from scratch ... you can also make one for your own. Hope this helps